# Excel: VBA script error Run-time error '2147417848 (80010108)'

Tags: vba, excel

Using the follow VBA codes to run two separate procedures which I am calling via separate buttons. 
Depending on the order I run them, I get the Run-time error:

- DeleteSheets1 = No error GetSheets - No error DeleteSheets1 + GetSheets - Error!
- DeleteSheets1, (Close and reopen Excel), GetSheets - NoError
- GetSheets, DeleteSheets1 - No Error
- GetSheets, GetSheets, GetSheets - No Error

---

```
Sub DeleteSheets1()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Name <> "Master" Then
        xWs.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

-------------------------------------------------

Sub GetSheets()
Dim path As String, Filename As String, sheet, Awb As Workbook

path = "mypathhere"
Filename = Dir(path & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
Set Awb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sheet In Awb.Worksheets
        sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Given that closing and reopening Excel prevents the error, I wonder if it is either memory based, or my delete sub is not clearing what is needed?

Comment: Just curious on your use of `ActiveWorkbook` in the `DeleteSheet1` Sub.  I had assumed that the `DeleteSheet1` would be to clear excess sheets from the workbook the code resides in; but for that, it would be better to use `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: What/where is `RunSheets`?

Comment: @BruceWayne fixed the typos - meant to write GetSheets

Comment: @Mistella thanks for the clarification. DeleteSheet1 seems to be working fine, but still crashing running GetSheets straight after.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a workable solution

```
Sub Reopen()
'Sets as active, saves and reopens workbook

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim pth As String
pth = wb.FullName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Application.Workbooks.Open(pth)
wb.Close (True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Calling the above procedure immediately following `DeleteSheets1`; Excel saves and reopens the Workbook. This clears the cache, meaning `GetSheets` runs without error.